# Printing the content of void methods in java

Tags: java, methods, void, println

Is there any way to print the contents of void methods just like this in java

```
 public boolean printings(String branchName){
 if (findBranch(branchName)!=null){
     myBranch.get(findTheBranch(branchName)).printCostumers();
     return true;
 }else{
     System.out.println("Branch does not exist");
     return false;
 }
}
```

Note that methods findTheBranch is working properly and the printCostumers is also a void method

```
private int findTheBranch(String name){
 for (int i=0;i<myBranch.size();i++){
     if (myBranch.get(i).getName().indexOf(name)>=0){
         return i;
     }
 }
 return -1;
```

}

```
public void printCostumers(){
    for(int i=0;i<myCostumer.size();i++){

        System.out.println(myCostumer.get(i).getName()+":" );
        for (int j=0; j<findTheCostumer(i).getTransaction().size();j++){
            System.out.println(findTheCostumer(i).getTransaction().get(j));
        }
    }
}
```

Other methods that are not mendtioned are working properly. I've tried them in other examples.

Comment: *"print the contents of void methods"* makes no sense, can you please explain what are you trying to do.

Comment: Why don't you simply step through your code using a debugger?

Comment: Dear down voters, while the OP clearly didn't understand his problem, it doesn't mean it isn't a legitimate problem for someone who hasn't internalized the specific semantics of keywords in programming languages. And based on this, this is actually a decent question, don't you think?

Comment: @AngeloFuchs The basics are well documented, and there are tons of tutorials (official & unofficial) online. Should we be re-explaining the basics to every new user, inflating the site with low-quality posts which people struggle to understand?

Comment: @VinceEmigh No, we should close all but the first as duplicates of that first. I actually did not find an answer on SO on this specific problem, or else I would have closed it.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs You didn't didn't a duplicate because this is *too* specific. Studying the basics would avoid misconceptions like this. What if I asked "*why can I put an* `if` *inside another* `if`, *like* `if(bool) { if(otherBool) { } }`", would you say that's a question that developers should invest time in? If so, we'd have an inflation of questions that get little traffic, since no one would be looking for this specific issue. SO aims to be a high quality Q&A repository, and questions like this do not contribute towards that goal.

Comment: @VinceEmigh This is getting interesting, but off topic. I opened a chat room for it: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177153/angelo-fuchs-and-vince-emigh-chat-about-which-questions-to-keep

Comment: Please do accept the answer if it helped you, or clarify your question if it didn't.

Answer (score 2):

Anywhere you include

```
System.out.println(String x);
```

Java will print out x. It doesn't matter whether or not it's in a void method.

`void` in Java just refers to the `return` statement (meaning a void method doesn't return anything). It doesn't mean that the method can't output something (on the console, window, printer or somewhere else)

Also concerning your actual code: Your loop most likely doesn't print anything as it most likely is handed an empty list.